# Keras model predict iteration getting slower.

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I have some problem about Keras with python 3.6 
My enviroment is keras with Python and Only CPU.

but the problem is when I iterate same Keras model for predict some diferrent input, its getting slower and slower..

my code is so simple just like that

```
for i in range(100):
   model.predict(x)
```

the First run is fast. it takes 2 seconds may be. but second run takes 3 seconds and Third takes 5 seconds... its getting slower and slower even if I use same input.

what can I iterate predict keras model hold fast? I don't want any getting slower.. it will be very critical.

How can I Fix IT??

Comment: why dont you pass everything at once?

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the same problem and can't find a solution..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras model.predict() slower on first iteration then gets faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577711/keras-model-predict-slower-on-first-iteration-then-gets-faster)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `__call__` method directly. The documentation of the predict method states the following:

> For small numbers of inputs that fit in one batch, directly use `__call__()` for faster execution, e.g., model(x).

I see the performance is critical in this case. So, if it doesn't help, you could use [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html) which is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU. Your performance should be much better than using Keras directly.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Save your model as SavedModel**

OpenVINO is not able to convert HDF5 model, so you have to save it as SavedModel first.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from custom_layer import CustomLayer
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.

Answer (score -1):

If your model calls the fit function in batches, there are different samples in the same batch with slightly different times over the course of the iteration, and then you try again and again to get more and more groups of predictive model performance time will be longer and longer.